# How to generate popup(usercontrol or div) on click of hyperlink residing in usercontrol of aspx?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ext.net

Project is based on Nhibernate & spring framework with ext.net controls .

I have a usercontrol UCA.ascx which has a hyperlink on click of which I want to generate a popup to show details . So what can be done ? Any help is welcome

Comment: I already tried to use javascript & even created a user control thinking if I could call usercontrol from usercontrol . I am not able to implement it properly . Can you guide me the right way , about what can be done in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute allows you set the target window of the anchor.

```
<a target="_blank" href="url"></a>
```

Comment: <a href='#' onclick='javascript:return CompX.deviceState({1});return false;'>ID</a>

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like this

```
       function openWindow() {
var URL = "/Test.aspx"
        window.open(URL);
        }
```

and call like this

```
    <a onclick="openWindow()" />
```

Comment: but in my case i have a usercontrol & not an aspx page

Comment: add your usercontrol in a page. Usercontrol cannot be rendered without a page.

Answer (score 0):

For popup you can use AJAX modal popup extender.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **JqueryUI Dialogue Box**.

[dialogue](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

add required `input` box inside the div which is going to popup.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
//show details here....
</div>
```

you can modify the div and add whatever controls you want inside it.

Comment: I modified the div adding all my controls inside it . Now I want to set property of ext.net controls by javascript or jquery , or an optimized alternative .

Comment: i am sure you must have given some id or class to controls you have added inside that div? now like normal DOM element you can set the property to these elements using jquery code.

Comment: I have a ext:label which has a property "CtCls" , now I want to set value "x" to it . So what should i do ?                               I tried by                                          document.getElementById("<%= lblpanelheader2.ClientID %>").setAttribute("CtCls","ArmedStayColor");     I even tried by  $("#<%=lblpanelheader2.ClientID%>").attr("CtCls","ArmedStayColor"); but no success .

Comment: document.getElementById("<%= lblpanelheader2.ClientID %>").setAttribute("CtCls","ArmedAwayColor");     document.getElementById("<%= ImgArmStatus.ClientID %>").setAttribute("ImageUrl","~/images/sysimages/armed_away_indicator.png");

Comment: give alert for id `<%= lblpanelheader2.ClientID %>` you have used.is it returning correct id?

Comment: Ya I am getting the right id , just want to set its 2 properties from jquery or javascript

Comment: use this `$(#<%= lblpanelheader2.ClientID %>).attr("CtCls","ArmedAwayColor");`

Comment: try this:
`$('#'+<%= lblpanelheader2.ClientID %>).attr("CtCls","ArmedAwayColor");`